# Getting RID Lookup instead of Table Scan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23cf8

In this query, when I have an `In` clause on an Id, and then also select other columns, the In is evaluated first, and then the Details column and other columns are pulled in via a RID Lookup:

```
--In production and in SQL Fiddle, Details is grabbed via a RID Lookup after the In clause is evaluated
    SELECT [Id]
      ,[ForeignId]    
     ,Details    
      --Generate a numbering(starting at 1) 
      --,Row_Number() Over(Partition By ForeignId Order By Id Desc) as ContactNumber --Desc because older posts should be numbered last
  FROM SupportContacts
  Where foreignId In (1,2,3,5)
```

With this query, the Details are being pulled in via a Table Scan.

```
With NumberedContacts AS 
(
    SELECT [Id]
      ,[ForeignId]
      --Generate a numbering(starting at 1) 
      ,Row_Number() Over(Partition By ForeignId Order By Id Desc) as ContactNumber --Desc because older posts should be numbered last
  FROM SupportContacts
  Where ForeignId In (1,2,3,5) 
)
Select nc.[Id]
      ,nc.[ForeignId]   
      ,sc.[Details]
From NumberedContacts nc
Inner Join SupportContacts sc on nc.Id = sc.Id
Where nc.ContactNumber <= 2 --Only grab the last 2 contacts per ForeignId
;
```

In SqlFiddle, the second query actually gets a RID Lookup, whereas in production with a million records it produces a Table Scan (the `IN` clause eliminates 99% of the rows)

Otherwise the query plan shown in SQL Fiddle is identical, the only difference being that for the second query the RID Lookup in SQL Fiddle, is a Table Scan in production :(

1. I would like to understand possibilities that would cause this behavior? What kinds of things would you look at to help determine the cause of it using a table scan here?
2. How can I influence it to use a RID Lookup there?

From looking at operation costs in the actual execution plan, I believe I can get the second query very close in performance to the first query if I can get it to use a RID Lookup. If I don't select the `Detail` column, then the performance of both queries is very close in production. It is only after adding other columns like `Detail` that performance degrades significantly for the second query. When I put it in SQL Fiddle and saw that the execution plan used an RID Lookup, I was surprised but slightly confused...

It doesn't have a clustered index because in testing with different clustered indexes, there was slightly worse performance for this and other queries. That was before I began adding other columns like `Details` though, and I can experiment with that more, but would like to have a understanding of what is going on now before I start shooting in the dark with random indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you would change your main index to include the `Details` column?

If you use:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SupportContacts_ForeignIdAsc_IdDesc] 
ON SupportContacts ([ForeignId] ASC, [Id] DESC)
INCLUDE (Details);
```

then neither a RID lookup nor a table scan would be needed, since your query could be satisfied from just the index itself....

Comment: maybe you meant this CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SupportContacts__Id] ON SupportContacts
([Id] ASC) INCLUDE([Details]);

Comment: I considered that index, but wondered if making such a large field part of the index would bloat the index alot and perhaps have a big impact on inserts/updates to that field?  Not trying to be difficult, just interested in your perspective on that.

Comment: @AaronLS: you didn't mention in detail just how big those columns are - and the beauty of the `INCLUDE` is: those values are stored **only** in the leaf level of the index - but **NOT** in the index structure above the leaf level! That's a very efficient and very nifty way to get performance - avoiding RID or key lookups can be a **massive** boost for your performance

Answer (score 1):

The differences in the query plans will be dependent on the types of indexes that exist and the statistics of the data for those tables in the different environments.

The optimiser uses the statistics (histograms of data frequency, mostly) and the available indexes to decide which execution plan is going to be the quickest.

So, for example, you have noticed that the performance degrades when the 'Details' column is included. This is an almost sure sign that either the 'Details' column is not part of an index, or if it is part of an index, the data in that column is mostly unique such that the index accesses would be equivalent (or almost equivalent) to a table scan.

Often when this situation arises, the optimiser will choose a table scan over the index access, as it can take advantage of things like block reads to access the table records faster than perhaps a fragmented read of an index.

To influence the path that will be chose by the optimiser, you would need to look at possible indexes that could be added/modified to make an index access more efficient, but this should be done with care as it can adversely affect other queries as well as possibly degrading insert performance.

The other important activity you can do to help the optimiser is to make sure the table statistics are kept up to date and refreshed at a frequency that is appropriate to the rate of change of the frequency distribution in the table data

Answer (score 1):

If it's true that 99% of the rows would be omitted if it performed the query using the relevant index + RID then the likeliest problem in your production environment is that your statistics are out of date and the optimiser doesn't realise that ForeignID in (1,2,3,5) would limit the result set to 1% of the total data.

Here's a good link for discovering more about statistics from Pinal Dave: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/25/sql-server-find-statistics-update-date-update-statistics/

As for forcing the optimiser to follow the correct path WITHOUT updating the statistics, you could use a table hint - if you know the index that your plan should be using which contains the ID and ForeignID columns then stick that in your query as a hint and force SQL optimiser to use the index:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

FYI, if you want the best performance from your second query, use this index and avoid the headache you're experiencing altogether:

```
create index ix1 on SupportContacts(ForeignID, Id DESC) include (Details);
```